# Subir archivos a un FTP con PowerShell

Tags: ftp, powershell

Buenas,

Estoy tratando de subir archivos a un FTP con PowerShell pero me da un error, si podéis aportar algo de luz os lo agradecería muchísimo.

```
$ftp = "ftp://192.168.0.2/" 
$user = "user" 
$pass = "pass"  
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  
$item="C:/Pruebas/origen/prueba.txt"
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 

Excepción al llamar a "UploadFile" con los argumentos "2": "Excepción durante una solicitud WebClient."
En línea: 8 Carácter: 1
+ $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21812641/579895)

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el error viene por la variable donde defines el archivo a subir:

```
$item="C:/Pruebas/origen/prueba.txt"
```

Y luego utilizas las propiedades *Name* y *FullName*:

```
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)
```

Ya que al ser un **string**, no es posible invocar esas propiedades. Lo más fácil es obtener los valores requeridos de la siguiente manera:

```
$itemName = "prueba.txt"
$itemFullName = "C:\Pruebas\origen\$itemName"
```

Y reemplazar el código con las nuevas variables:

```
$ftp = "ftp://192.168.0.2/" 
$user = "user" 
$pass = "pass"  
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  
$itemName = "prueba.txt"
$itemFullName="C:/Pruebas/origen/$itemName"
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$itemName) 
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $itemFullName)
```

Puede que no sea la mejor manera, pero debería funcionar.